# How can I prevent an object to be destroyed after I used the function: .load() in javascript (three.js)

Tags: javascript, scope, three.js

I am trying to prevent the destroying of my object after I loaded it.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
var rescue;
loader.load(
    'Improved_Person_Maker_better_quality.dae',
    function(collada) {
        scene.add(collada.scene);
        collada.scene.position.set(-25, 1, 25);
        collada.scene.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
        rescue = collada.scene;
    },
    function(xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
    }
);

rescue.position.set(-20, 1, 25);
```

The last statement is not possible, because the loaded mesh does not exist any more. Is there a way to rescue collada.scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A really great thank goes here to [Stallion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2240420/stallion) and [Westlangley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461008/westlangley) for giving me the right hint with the asynchronous loading.

I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22976704/asynchronous-issue-with-objloader-wait-for-xhr-to-finish-loading) but I will reproduce it, too.

The solution is to create a normal THREE.Object3d() object. It is possible to add every object as a child of another. So I did the following:

```
loadObject: function(){
    var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
    var container = new THREE.Object3D();
     loader.load(
'Improved_Person_Maker_better_quality.dae',
function ( collada ) {
    container.add(collada.scene);
},
function ( xhr ) {
    console.log( (xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded' );

});
    return container;
}
```

For flexibilty reasons I created a new function.

Answer (score 0):

The loader is asynchronous.

That means `rescue.position.set()` is being called before `rescue` is defined in the loader callback.

Just set the position in the callback, which you have done.

If you must refer to `rescue` later in your code, you can use this pattern

```
if ( rescue !== undefined ) {
    // your code
}
```

three.js r.75

Comment: I also tried your solution but rescue is always undefined, so I won't be able to set a new position to the object.

Comment: Always undefined? You set it in the callback. You have a scoping problem in your code unrelated to the issue.

Comment: Always undefined after I declared rescue = collada.scene

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var rescue; 
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onProgress = function(item, loaded, total) {
    console.log(item, loaded, total);
};
manager.onLoad = function(){
       rescue.position.set(-20, 1, 25);
};
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader(manager);
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

loader.load("<url path for the file>", function(collada) {
       scene.add(collada.scene);
       collada.scene.position.set(-25, 1, 25);
       collada.scene.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
       rescue = collada.scene;
    }, function(xhr) {
        console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100) + '% loaded');
});
}
```

Loading Manager provide you flexibility of the async manage loading so that later point you can have multiple files.

Comment: Tried your solution but the object is not movin at all.
rescue is still not defined.